# selenium-side-runner can't find the chromedriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I installed selenium-side-runner and the browser driver, in my case, Chrome Driver.

When i put `chromedriver -version` in cmd responds correctly:

[image]

I have also added the folder where *chromedriver.exe* is located in the PATH but when I execute `selenium-side runner command` in cmd it generates the following error:

[image]

Comment: Which directory were you in when you typed `chromedriver -version`?

Comment: And have you restarted your computer since modifying your PATH?

Comment: Yes I restarted my pc and I was in my user's global directory

Comment: There is no such thing as your user's "global" directory... I'm assuming you meant profile directory. Hm. What happens when you type `where chromedriver` on the command line?

Comment: I have solved it, just change the location of the chrome driver. it's very strange

Comment: Change the location in what way? I'm having the same issue...